# Creating table of content with the package titletoc in Org Mode for LaTex export produces strange lines of text

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I use the LaTeX package `titletoc` to produce table of contents in some chapters or sections for Org-Mode LaTeX / PDF export with

```
#+TOC: headlines 1 local
```

But in the PDF file there is for example the following text before the table of content:

> section.1 section.2 section.3 subsection.3.1 subsubsection.3.1.1 subsubsection.3.1.2
>   subsubsection.3.1.3 subsubsection.3.1.4 subsubsection.3.1.5 subsection.3.2

I have no idea about that. Perhaps somebody can give me a hint.

Comment: Did you turn off the normal TOC as [the manual indicates](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Table-of-contents)? Also, did you customize `org-latex-default-packages-alist` to load `titletoc` *before* `hyperref`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like NickD wrote you have to load `titletoc` before `hyperref`.

My problem was that `hyperref` is loaded automatically through the variable `org-lates-default-packages-alist` and I defined my packages on a per file basis. So `hyperref` will always be loaded before the packages defined in the Org-Mode file. I have it now in my `init.el`.

Turning off the normal TOC has no effect or rather makes no problem if turned on.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to mark the question closed.